# knockoutjs and jQuery mobile - checkbox doesnt update value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

When binding a checkbox to the checked binding and using jQuery mobile the observable does not get updated when the enhanced checkbox is checked.

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JwsrW/12/)

I have looked at the code for both libraries and it seems that `knockoutjs` is bound to the click event, yet jQuery mobile only updates the checked value which does not fire this event, i have fudged around with hacks to try to get this working with no joy..

Does anyone have a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this, but have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vQRWQ/

I've added a new `bindingHandler`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkbox = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = valueAccessor();

        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value); 

        $(element).attr("checked", valueUnwrapped).checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
};
```

And used the "event" binding:

```
data-bind="event: {change: function(){ checked(!checked()); } }, checkbox: checked"
```